# Android build error com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8

Tags: java, android, firebase

Tried connect my project in android with firebase, but when add dependencies and run project, have an error.

I tried different versions of the firebase core but the same error message still appears, I also raised the level of the API and the minimum SDK but it is still not functional.

gradle code is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.amazonaws.appsync'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.example'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 26
        versionName "2.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
    implementation 'me.anwarshahriar:calligrapher:1.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:2.6.+'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.+'
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+') { transitive = true }
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.0'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
    implementation files('libs/java-json.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

When  try installing app show this error:

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
>
> error: cannot access zzbck
> class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbck not found

Comment: You're mixing a really old version of play-services with a very new version of firebase-core.  You should make sure they are both up to date with each other.  Also your Android support libraries are old.  Best case, make sure everything is up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update to the latest versions of play-services and firebase.

Also you should avoid using bundled version of Google Play services. Google Play services 
 can be selectively included, which enables a smaller APK size.

E.g.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'
```

or at least

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
```